# how is this transformer working with DC?

Tags: transformer, ac, dc, basic

As I was going through the SMPS circuits online I came across this circuit:

[image]

I searched and learned that the transformer steps down or step up only AC power supplies and then converted to DC using rectifiers and to boost or to decrease them we use buck booster circuits.

I also found that :

As in DC(voltage being always constant), the change in flux is zero so no mutual induction,thus transformers can't work with a DC supply. Moreover, if DC or a similar rating of AC(Voltage & Current) is fed into the terminals of a Transformer there is a high possibility that it would burn the primary coil.

When a dc supply is provided to the transformer primary no self-induced emf will be generated (no back emf). Therefore heavy current will flow in the transformer primary winding which may result in burning down the transformer primary winding.

I also found the above things on Quora:

https://www.quora.com/Will-a-transformer-work-with-DC

https://www.quora.com/What-will-happen-if-a-DC-voltage-is-given-to-the-transformer-primary

https://www.quora.com/How-does-a-DC-transformer-work

The transformer used in this circuit is an SMPS transformer that works on high frequencies. So how this works. I am not able understand it.

Comment: Simple answer - the transformer does not work with DC. Look carefully at the schematic. There's a big MOSFET in series with the primary transformer winding and a feedback circuit from secondary to primary which controls the gate voltage. What must the MOSFET be doing to prevent the transformer from seeing DC?

Comment: So is MOSFET pulsating the DC so that the transformer will get a pulsating voltage and it will induce emf?

Comment: Pulsating DC frequency.

Comment: @Dave Tweed as you said the answer was the same as them I want to know regarding the DC current flow through the transformer as stated it would burn the coils or am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: You're understanding it wrong. DC **voltage** across a coil will cause the current to rise uncontrollably, leading to burnout. But a DC **current** through a coil causes no problems at all, unless the resistive losses (\$I^2R\$) are too high. The SMPS is doing the latter, not the former.

Comment: A DC voltage applied to an inductor produces a current ramp, so long as the inductor does not hit Bmax and saturate out - it will not immediately burn. Just rearrange the canonical inductor equation V_L = L * di / dt and you will see it. Pulsing the DC means the volt-seconds applied will not exceed Bmax, plus the transformer has time to 'reset' during the off-time so that saturation is avoided.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. @DaveTweed thank you so much now it's clear.
And **Adam Lawrence** thanks to you also.